# How to fix RSpec SystemStackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

Given code similar to

```
module UserDecorator
  def profile
    "Hi, my name is #{name}"
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

describe UserDecorator do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  let(:decorated_user) { user.decorate }

  describe '#profile' do
    it 'uses #name' do
      expect(decorated_user).to receive(:name).and_call_original
      decorated_revenue_report_view.profile
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  1) UserDecorator#profile uses name
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-mocks-3.3.2/lib/rspec/mocks/argument_list_matcher.rb:65
     # 
     #   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
     #   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
     #   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
```

It seems to be a heisen-bug - if I have some other specs running first, I don't get a SystemStackError.

How can I fix it?

I'm using RSpec 3.3.0 and Rails 4.1.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be expecting `decorated_user` to receive `name`, as opposed to `user`. Changing the spec to

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UserDecorator do
  let(:user) { build(:user) }
  let(:decorated_user) { user.decorate }

  describe '#profile' do
    it 'uses User#name' do
      expect(user).to receive(:name).and_call_original
      decorated_revenue_report_view.profile
    end
  end
end
```

seemed to fix the problem. I suspect it's something to do with `decorated_user` having both a delegation of `name` to the decorated object `user`, and having RSpec having to handle `name`, but I can't say for certain.

This has been reported, and the owners are [treating it as a bug](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/1016#issuecomment-145296328).